# storing an array on the server side. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

How do I go about storing my array on the server side as opposed to the client side? I want the data to be available to multiple devices and needs to always be up to date. I'm able to scrape together enough JavaScript to do what I need to on the client side I just need a way of pulling the latest array from the server, updating it, then putting it back. From my research so far it seems like I'll have to install node.js on the server then run something likeexpress. From then on it all gets fuzzy for me. Anyone got any links to good tutorial? Thanks in advance. Ben.

Comment: You need some server part, but it doesn’t have to be Node. You could use Python or PHP, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is data persistence that is accessible to multiple users of a site. Traditionally you do need a server (such as node, php, etc.) to handle data being sent (GET) or received (POST). You would then need to link your data to something that can store it such as MySQL or MongoDB. You technically don't have to use one of those services and can use the server's file system to read and write to a text file, but that is not recommended. As a side note, you typically do not store data as a string or an array, but you would have it in JSON format, which can include an array within it.

There is quite a learning curve to setting up the server, then connecting it to a database, then learning how to use the database. If you are looking for something quick and easy, you should look into [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). It abstracts the whole server and database learning curve away from you and you can link it directly to your frontend code. This is a good way to get an understanding of how a NoSQL database works without having to worry too much about deploying and such.

Comment: Google fire base is looking promising. All I'm looking to do is create a turn roster that can be accessed from any browser. When a button is pushed the user goes to the bottom of the list. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

An array is just a data type, like a string or a hash. It's not something you "store on the server side".

Generally what you need is a "data store"... either a database (mySQL, Postgres), Redis, a JS cookie, or even something as simple as writing to a file in the harddrive.

Either way, the request comes in with the data (whether its an array, a string, or whatever), then your backend code will store that data. Any number of google searches can yield helpful results, like "Store record mysql php".

From there, when a second request comes in, you simply retrieve the data using the proper identifier (a lot of this comes down to what youre actually trying to do)